# How to Start Using Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I have already completed installation of Ubuntu alongside Windows. When I try to launch Ubuntu, it's either my screen just shows zigzags or the desktop launches but I cannot do anything on it. It would show the Keyboard Shortcuts, which I cannot close. There is also an error message at the upper left corner that says "System program problem detected" and asks if I want to report the problem. I'm trying to do something, but my mouse pointer won't even move anywhere.

Comment: press <Ctrl>+<Alt>+<F2> then <Ctrl>+<Alt>+<F7> for bypass your mouse from freez and then click to report the problem and then run update app from dash to update your Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstall **ubuntu**.
It might be a corrupt version. It could also be a different architecture (32bit / 64bit).

Your mouse could be having a driver related problem also. Use keyboard's *"super"(Windows)* key to open dash. Search Additional drivers. Install your mouse's drivers their. Reboot and check if it works!!

Answer (score -2):

if you have NVIDIA drivers you may need to replace them. search NVIDIA web site for NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-346.35.run